# start VM on RDP request

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, rdp

I have a windows 10 VM in azure. I connect to this machine RDP. Because most of the time this machine is not in use (I'm not using it) I'd like, in order to save the costs, to shut down it. 
My issue is to get back, to connect to it RDP after that. How do I start the machine remotely?

Comment: I may be wrong but I don't think this can be done over RDP. As far as I'm aware, it can only be done using a VM manager. Personally, I use vSphere. The free noncommercial version can be downloaded [here](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/playerpro-evaluation.html).

Comment: You could start your VM remotely by using PowerShell or Azure Portal.

Comment: If you shut down your VM inside the VM, you need pay for the VM cost. You need stop VM by using Portal, PowerShell, Azure CLI.

Comment: I didn't know that a computer that was shut down still costs on azure! Shut down should (in real world do) turn off the computer! I should check this!

Answer (score -1):

If you shutdown VM inside VM, you continue to pay for your VM.

> If you shut down a VM from inside ( using Windows power options) or
>   through PowerShell by calling ShutdownRoleOperation with
>   "PostShutdownAction" equal to "Stopped".

More information please refer to this [FAQ](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/virtual-machines/windows/) and this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_shep/2013/06/10/azure-billing-per-minute-and-no-compute-charge-for-a-stopped-iaas-vm/).

You should use Portal or PowerShell to stop your VM.

If your VM is stopped(deallocated), you could use PowerShell to start your VM.

```
Start-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $myResourceGroup -Name $myVM
```

More information about manage Azure Virtual Machines using PowerShell please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-ps-manage#start-a-virtual-machine).

Also, you could start your VM on [Azure portal](http://portal.azure.com). More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-hero-tutorial).

Notes: If you don't set static Public IP, the IP address will change.